# Why do some Https download links not have a padlock in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, security, browser, download, https

Why when you go to some download links by typing / pasting in the address bar in Firefox (in Windows 10), does it show https, but there is no padlock? (Similar might be seen in other browsers)

Random examples:-

```
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=121721&arch=x64

https://www.avast.com/download-thank-you.php?product=FAV-ONLINE&direct=1
```

Comment: Why would the browser show a padlock when these are download links? A document is not displayed, secure or otherwise.

Comment: Firefox has well documented rules when showing the padlock icon.  They have also changed over the years.

Comment: @dan Thank you, that seems to make sense, the window is white with the download window on top.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, I looked at some Firefox information, but could find nothing that fits. Are you thinking of something specific?

Comment: @Eric - Mozilla and Google both went the direction of providing icons to indicate a HTTPS website is NOT secure, instead of indicating when a link is secure, since the majority of the internet is secure by default.

Comment: The rules for the padlock icon, is also primarily universal, across all Chromium browsers by the way